# stats is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code load the content of the php file with the parameter: online and name and print them  dynamic every 0.2s, the whole  code works, but it says that " stats " is not defined in internet explore, i dont know why. Help me out guys

```
function updateStats(stat)
{
    var stat = ["online","name"];


   var stats = "";


 if (stat==undefined)
{
document.write("is undefined");
}
    var url = "online.php";

    $.each(stat, function(i, key){
       $.post(url, {stats: key}, function(data) { 
          $("#" + key).html(data);       
       });
    });
} 

setInterval('updateStats("updateStats")', 200); //  200 milliseconds = 0.2 seconds
```

**this is the updated code, but still says that stats not defined**

```
function updateStats(stat)
{


var stat = ["online","money"];


if (typeof stat == "undefined")
{
document.write("stat is undefined");
}
    var url = "online.php";

    $.each(stat, function(i, key){
       $.post(url, {stats: key}, function(data) { // stats to stat
          $("#" + key).html(data);       
       });
    });
} 


setInterval(function(){
  updateStats("updateStats");
}, 1000);


if (typeof stats == "undefined")
{
document.write("stats is undefined");
}
```

Comment: That's a rather cranky and pointless piece of code, but it **does** work in IE (7, 8 and 9). There must be something else.

Comment: The whole code is a bit chaotic. Why do you have two variables `stat` and `stats`? `stat` is actually the parameter name of the function. Why are you assigning an array to it?

Comment: I know, just wanted to define stats, well that wrong.. going delete it now :)

Comment: @user1417815 What is the precise error? Do you get into your own document.write("stat is undefined") or do you get an error from the Javascript engine?

Comment: At the moment as i interpret your code, there should be an error from the JS-Engine saying stats is not defined as you use it without defining it in `$.post(url, {stats: key}`

Comment: you accepted the answer - did you fix your problem?

Comment: Yes i removed: <body onLoad="updateStats(stats); from the index file, then internet explore 8 stop with the complain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
setInterval('updateStats("updateStats")', 200);
```

To:

```
setInterval(function(){
  updateStats("updateStats");
}, 200);
```

Also to check if something is `undefined`, instead of:

```
if (stat==undefined)
```

Use:

```
if (typeof stat == "undefined")
```

---

Also  as pointed out by @Felix Kling, you are passing `stat` variable via function:

```
updateStats(stat)
```

And also creating it later on inside that function:

```
var stat = ["online","name"];
```

which is weird, you should modify your code to account for that.

Comment: `setInterval(updateStats("updateStats"), 200);` might be sufficient, no? Also `===` should be used for comparison.

Comment: No, the argument of `setInterval` must be a function. Anyway, this whole answer isn't the point of the questione.

Comment: @Christoph: No you cant call a function with argument without using anonymous function in `setInterval`

Comment: But now its blocking for my other scripts

Comment: @Christoph You don't want to pass the _result_ of calling `updateStats("updateStats")` to `setInterval`…

Comment: @Christoph I mean, a function or a string.

Comment: @DonalFellows well, thats true, nonetheless MaxArt your second answer is also wrong.

Comment: @Sarfraz i still have the same problem, still says it not defined

Comment: @user1417815 are you confusing `stat` and `stats`? Post your updated code please.

Comment: @Christoph I don't see any mistake in my comments. Can you explain?

Comment: This my updated code: function updateStats(stat)
{


var stat = ["online","money"];

   
if (typeof stat == "undefined")
{
document.write("stat is undefined");
}
    var url = "online.php";

    $.each(stat, function(i, key){
       $.post(url, {stats: key}, function(data) { // stats to stat
          $("#" + key).html(data);       
       });
    });
} 


if (typeof stats == "undefined")
{
document.write("stats is undefined");
}

setInterval(function(){
  updateStats("updateStats");
}, 1000);

Comment: @MaxArt you can pass a function call to setInterval. This is neither string nor function, but in this situation not applicable because you want to call the function with each interval not pass the result as Donal correctly stated.

Comment: @Christoph No, you can't pass something different than a function or an evaluable string to `setInterval`. IE raises an argument exception if you do that, while other browsers just don't do anything.

Comment: @Christoph: That is not "passing a function call" then. It's passing the result of a function call which should be either a function or a string. The value matters, not where it came from.